# How to locate a docker container repo from data in the DockerFile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am looking at a DockerFile which someone else provided me, and I see that its extending an existing one:

> FROM php:7.2.11-apache

There are many docker images on dockerhub that deal with php/apache. Is therea way for me to do a lookup to know exactly which one this uses? (I mainly want to know so that I can look up configuration documentation on the dockerhub page).

Comment: Can't you lookup at dockerhub registry and search what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `php:7.2.11-apache` then you can find it here on [page #6](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=6) of PHP offical image with [build history](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2-apache/images/sha256-b4bb42a49b71eec5625673ba48e9aef18fc3d2a31aa50918500ab1bf0f1cb302) .

Here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/buster/apache/Dockerfile) on Github offical.

Comment: Is there a standardized way of finding that, or was it trial and error or you simply already knew? To better explain my question: in composer, we define a repo by its vendor/package, and you can find things on gitbub this way. It sort of looks like you could do this for dockerhub, but instead it uses php:7.2.11-apache... Here's an example of what I was expecting of vendor/package: https://hub.docker.com/r/skilldlabs/mailhog